# Linq auto converting string to single on comparison

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to do a simple string comparison in linq between two strings. 
The strings are sizes and some of the sizes have a decimal within the string like "2.75". I get an error when comparing strings in the table against strings with decimals, saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Single' to type 'System.String'" Type checking within the debugger reveals that it is a string before the comparison. Why is this happening, and how can I make sure that strings with decimals inside get treated as strings?

```
var results = from item in _table.AsEnumerable()
                  where item.Field<string>("Width") == _size.Width &&
                         item.Field<string>("Length") == _size.Length
                  select item;
```

Comment: Strings should be compared using `.Equals()` are you sure you are using the correct comparison? Is `item.Field<string>("...")` supposed to be a numeric value (`double` or `float`)?

Comment: @ChrisStillwell "strings are compared using .Equals()"? Did you notice that question tagged with C# and not Java?

Comment: either convert the field to a Single: `Convert.ToSingle(item.Field<string>("Width"))` or use `_size.Width.ToString()` so you're comparing like types. The `single` conversion will most likely be more accurate, but it will throw an exception if the conversion fails.

Comment: Also, you might want to read the section titled [Precision in Comparisons (at this link)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t24f0axa(v=vs.110).aspx). Comparing floating point types for equality can produce unexpected `false` results due to differences in precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the read values into singles:

```
var results = from item in _table.AsEnumerable()
              where Convert.ToSingle(item.Field<string>("Width")) == _size.Width &&
                    Convert.ToSingle(item.Field<string>("Length")) == _size.Length
              select item;
```

or

```
var results = from item in _table.AsEnumerable()
              let width = Convert.ToSingle(item.Field<string>("Width"))
              let length = Convert.ToSingle(item.Field<string>("Length"))
              where (width == _size.Width) && (length == _size.Length)
              select item;
```

to make it more readable